# Android blur app, must keep EXIF

Tags: android, photography, image-editor, privacy, face-recognition

I very often need to remove people faces in pictures, and am looking for an Android app to help with this task.

Requirements:

- The app must be available in Android's "Share to" menu for pictures.
- Must not remove EXIF data.
- Must work offline, and not do anything on the cloud.
- Free, ideally open source.

Bonus:

- Ideally the app would [not change the pixels at all](https://github.com/MATHEMA-GmbH/privacyblur/issues/79) in unmodified parts of the picture (lossless JPEG transformation).
- Ideally the app should allow me to set my saving preferences, with at least these options:

  - overwrite
  - save as a different file
  - share to another app
- Ideally the app would detect and blur faces automatically or semi-automatically, but if no app does that then doing it manually is OK too.

I am currently using PointBlur but it removes EXIF so I am looking for another one.

Comment: Did you have a look at [PrivacyBlur](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.mathema.privacyblur/) (I'm linking to F-Droid, especially as you hilight privacy topics; the app is also [available at Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mathema.privacyblur) if you insist)? Works pretty well to blur sensitive areas (I did the review when it was added at F-Droid – I however missed to check whether it touches Exif data, hence just a comment for now).

Comment: @Izzy: I just tried PrivacyBlur, and realized that not supporting "share to" intents makes it too painful to use. I edited my question and submitted [a feature request](https://github.com/MATHEMA-GmbH/privacyblur/issues/76). Also, it [removes EXIF](https://github.com/MATHEMA-GmbH/privacyblur/issues/77).

Comment: Oh, sad to read. They might be open to suggestions, though – good idea with the feature request hence (and good examples you've given for both)! Looks like they take the term "Privacy" in the app's name quite serious, not only blurring visibles but also removing the metadata makes sense in most cases. But so do your examples :) Best luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JPEG Cropper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.kame.jpegcropper) allows many lossless operations on JPEG, including blurring.

1. In your usual gallery, select the picture you want to blur.
2. Tap "Share to"
3. Select "JPEG Cropper"
4. Tap "Pixelate"
5. Add a pixelation area
6. Move and resize it as you wish
7. Set the pixelation granularity as you wish
8. Add more pixelation areas if needed.

Gratis. Does not remove EXIF.

[image]